# Script para reconhecer similaridade entre imagens

Tags: python, imagem, opencv, processamento-de-imagens

Boa Tarde Pessoal, tudo bem?

Estou iniciando meus estudos em Python conjunto ao OpenCV, e desejo realizar a leitura de imagens e exibir o grau de similaridade entre elas.

Ex: Possuo uma base de dados com várias imagens, irei entregar ao script uma outra imagem de outra base de dados, e ela terá de procurar a imagem mais similar na base de dados atual.

É possível realizar tal ação?

OBS: Achei algumas dicas em alguns fóruns , porém, a maioria estava comparando apenas 2 imagens já entregues ao script, e apenas retornava True ou False caso fosse similar, e não o seu grau, ou a respectiva imagem que é similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar significa o quão parecidas são as imagens, isso é processamento de imagens + reconhecimento de padrões, você está em busca de características que são similares entre duas ou mais imagens. Sugiro buscar por tais termos no google, você pode usar um SIFT + KNN, por exemplo, para compará-las.

Nessa pergunta, ele faz isso com o SIFT, esse algoritmo vc encontra no Python:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500498/how-to-use-sift-algorithm-to-compute-how-similar-two-images-are

Comment: Obrigado! Me deu um bom horizonte